# How do I enable source map generation when using "webdev build"?

Tags: dart

When using Dart 2 and the `webdev build` command, I get a `build/main.dart.js` file. At the end of this file, there is a comment pointing the source map:

`//# sourceMappingURL=main.dart.js.map`

However, this file doesn't exist. How do I get the .map file and Dart source files to show up in the build directory so that Chrome devtools will see them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the document of [webdev build](https://github.com/dart-lang/webdev), you should use `webdev build --no-release` instead. (but this will use DDC compiler instead.)

**Update info**:
By default, `webdev build` in release mode will remove all *.js.map file, so you can put a build.yaml file in your project root folder to deactivate dart cleanup source.

For example, (build.yaml file)

`targets:
  $default:
    builders:
      build_web_compilers|dart_source_cleanup:
        release_options:
          enabled: false`

Answer (score 1):

I was able to use the generated file in `.dart_tool\build\generated\{PROJECT}\web\main.dart.js.map` as source map of my `main.dart.js`. Just copy the file to the location of web build directory, then reload page.

(webdev: v2.7.10)

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an exact answer for your question. I ended up calling dart2js manually to get unminified code.

> dart2js -o app.js web/app.dart